# Where is the MetaMask google plugin keypair located?

Tags: metamask, keystore

I've created a couple of Ethereum accounts in Metamax google plug in and want to use these accounts in a program I'm creating.

To do this I obviously need the key pair, but I cannot find them.

Any help?

Cheers,
Coen

Comment: you could export your private key from metamask to use it

Comment: I suppose I could, if I only new how

Comment: i've shared some screen shoots for how to export the private key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export the private key from Metamask is quite easy :

[image]

[image]